# How do I use services in Angular to store variables?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How do I use services to store variables so that I can access it in previous controller on pressing back button?
 **For example:**

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myservice) {
 console.log(myservice.myvar.myval)
 // output: undefined pressing back button
  });

.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, myservice) {
myservice.myvar.myval = "This I want in controller myCtrl on pressing back button"
 console.log(myservice.myvar.myval)
// outputs the value
});
```

If services are not the best approach and I should use `$rootScope`then will it do the job.

**P.S** `angular.module` and `myservice` are defined.

Comment: i suggest to you also to think about localstorage instaed of $rootScope ..cause store information in $rootScope is very heavy for perfomance and then in localstorage is more persistente

Comment: That is a nice workaround. I will use that if nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **getter-setter** for this.
For Example:

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.service('myservice', function () {
   this.myval = "value";
   this.getValue = function () { return this.myval }; //getter
   this.setValue = function (val) { this.myval = val }; //setter
})

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myservice) {
  console.log(myservice.getValue());
  // get the value here
 });

.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, myservice) {
   myservice.setValue("This I want in controller myCtrl on pressing back button");
  // Set the value here
});
```

> This is for the reference only. Please don't copy-paste and run code.

Comment: May pleasure :) @Sam

Answer (score 1):

Angular services are singletons and can be freely shared among components, which have access to dependency injection. You can define a closure with a module pattern of getters and setters or directly attach properties to the object you intend to return.

Answer (score 0):

I see 4 options, you can store it in a service, in $rootScope, in localStorage for persistent storage, and in sessionStorage to store datas only during the application lifetime. There's btw a nice module that wrap localStorage and sessionStorage, and make its use simpler :

http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage